# Understand different servers (v50, v95) in CloudKit Latency Telemetry

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit, latency, telemetry

I'm migrating to CloudKit from Firebase, the database isn't in production yet. Trying to improve the asset downloading speed I opened Telemetry, and under Latency i found this data:

```
12/31/2023, 8:00:00 AM UTC  
• v95      2.43 sec  
• v50      14 ms
```

What does that v95 and v50 mean? And is there a way to use v50 more often, so the images are downloaded quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's simply percentiles!

**v90 (90th percentile):** 90% of requests are faster than this value and 10% is slower.

So, in my case 50% of requests are faster than 14ms, and 5% are slower than 2.43 sec.